# Tell when stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: has completed

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm using a standard `UIWebView` and need to know when `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` has completed. I know a `WKWebView` has a completion handler, but I need to use the current `UIWebView` which I was given. Since the method needs to run on the main thread GCD wasn't of much help. Any suggestions?

```
-(void)insertValue:(NSString*)value inWebView:(UIWebView*)webView{
    NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:kConstantJSString, value];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: jsString];
    NSLog("THIS SHOULD LOG WHEN JS HAS EXECUTED");
}
```

Comment: But `[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]` is synchronous and will not return until all javascript code is evaluated. Perhaps the code your executing launches another async task (in javascript), that's why you feel that is not synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out a good way to do this.
In your javascript call add add this line to the end of your script :

`window.location = 'js-ObjC:jsCompleted';`

Then use the UIWebView's shouldStartLoadWithRequest: method in order to capture and test for this new window location. I then called a selector with the name of the second component in the new window location.

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{
 if ([[[request URL] absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"js-ObjC:"]) { //get location change
     NSArray *components = [[[request URL]absoluteString] componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
     NSString *functionName = [components objectAtIndex:1];

     /* Calls selector for functionName, this way silences compiler warning */
     SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(functionName);
     ((void (*)(id, SEL))[self methodForSelector:selector])(self, selector);

     return NO;
 }
return YES;
```

}

```
-(void)jsCompleted{
    //Do stuff after javascript has completed
```

}